# Efficient way to show the Associativity of $\oplus: E \times E \rightarrow E,\ x\oplus y \equiv x+y \bmod 5$

Tags: field-theory, associativity

Let $E:=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ be a set and let $\oplus$ be an internal binary operation on $E$ such that 
$$\oplus: E \times E \rightarrow E,\ x\oplus y \equiv x+y \bmod 5$$

So, we have:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\oplus & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\  \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

I need to conclude the associativity of $\oplus$ on $E$ by using the above table.

Is there an efficient way to conclude that without going through all $5\cdot5\cdot5= 125$ possibilities?

Comment: *Hint* Use the definition of $\oplus$ and the associativity of $+$.

Comment: What does [5] mean?

Comment: Let $a, b, c \in E$. To show that $\oplus$ is associative, show that $(a \oplus b) \oplus c = a \oplus (b \oplus c)$. As @Travis has suggested, using the associativity of $+$ should make this doable

Comment: @Travis The question is how to conclude the associativity by using the given table not by using the equation of associativity.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what exactly you mean by "using the given table" then. Using the symmetry of the table, it only takes $\frac{1}{2}(5)(5 + 1) = 15$ checks to show that $\oplus$ is actually given by the given algebraic rule, after which you can freely use that characterization.

Comment: If this is somehow disallowed, you can use, for example, that the permutation $(1243)$ is an automorphism of $\oplus$, you can deduce that it's enough to check the cases $a = 0, 1$, and the case $a = 0$ follows quickly from the fact that (again, checking the entries in the first row and column) $0$ is an identity, leaving just $5^2 = 25$ cases to check. But checking that that permutation defines an isomorphism requires $2 \cdot 25 = 50$ table lookups, or $30$ if you use the apparent commutativity of $\oplus$ (equivalently the symmetry of its multiplication table).

Comment: But in that case, the problem is not very natural---the right way to check this is to identify the operation with something you already know to be associative.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove the associativity "using the table" yo have to do all $125$ cases, or else have to give a law describing the buildup of the table.

What I want to say: Your problem can be solved only by doing the $125$ cases using the associativity in ${\mathbb Z}$ individually, or by proving once and for all "abstractly" that the addition in ${\mathbb Z}_5$ (or a similar quotient structure) is again associative. Then your table just has to do with the naming of the equivalence classes.